# Binary serializing on sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, serialization, binary

I am currently implementing a c# client to my C++ server. The communication protocol is binary. On the server side, there is no problem, since binary serilization is just a matter of memcpy. However, my C# client has trouble sending the data through the sockets.

First of all, here are my data structures:

The header:

```
[Serializable]
public class Header
{
    public UInt32 UserId { get; set; }
    public UInt16 CheckSum { get; set; }
    public byte Status { get; set; }
    public byte Command { get; set; }
    public byte Device { get; set; }
    public byte Method { get; set; }
    public byte KeepAlive { get; set; }
    public byte Osef { get; set; }
    public Header()
    {
        UserId = 0;
        CheckSum = 0;
        Status = 0;
        Command = 0;
        Device = 0;
        Method = 0;
        KeepAlive = 0;
        Osef = 0;
    }
    public static UInt16 Size()
    {
            return Convert.ToUInt16(sizeof(byte) * 6 + sizeof(UInt32) + sizeof(UInt16));
    }

    internal void write(Stream stream)
    {
        BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);

        writer.Write(UserId);
        writer.Write(CheckSum);
        writer.Write(Status);
        writer.Write(Command);
        writer.Write(Device);
        writer.Write(Method);
        writer.Write(KeepAlive);
        writer.Write(0); //alignement
    }

    internal void read(Stream stream)
    {
        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);

        UserId = reader.ReadUInt32();
        CheckSum = reader.ReadUInt16();
        Status = reader.ReadByte();
        Command = reader.ReadByte();
        Device = reader.ReadByte();
        Method = reader.ReadByte();
        KeepAlive = reader.ReadByte();
        reader.ReadByte(); //alignement
    }
}
```

A data structure with the header first:

```
[Serializable]
class UserPass
{
    public Header Header { get; set; }
    public UInt16 User_checkSum { get; set; }
    public byte[] Username { get; set; }
    public UInt16 Pass_checkSum { get; set; }
    public byte[] Password { get; set; }

    public UInt16 Size()
    {
        return Convert.ToUInt16((sizeof(byte) * 128) + (sizeof(byte) * 128) + sizeof(UInt16) * 2);
    }

    public UserPass()
    {
        Header = new Header();
        User_checkSum = 0;
        Username = new byte[128];
        Pass_checkSum = 0;
        Password = new byte[128];
    }

    internal void write(Stream stream)
    {
        BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);

        Header.write(stream);
        writer.Write(User_checkSum);
        writer.Write(Username, 0, 128);
        writer.Write(Pass_checkSum);
        writer.Write(Password, 0, 128);
    }

    internal void read(Stream stream)
    {
        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);

        Header.read(stream);
        User_checkSum = reader.ReadUInt16();
        Username = reader.ReadBytes(User_checkSum);
        Pass_checkSum = reader.ReadUInt16();
        Password = reader.ReadBytes(Pass_checkSum);
    }
}
```

I write my data using the write functions of Header and UserPass and passing a NetworkStream as argument that i converted from my socket with GetStream.

The problem is that the server receives the header properly, with each field containing the values initialized by the client, but the rest of the data is filled with zeros.

- I have tried using the same BinaryWriter Object for both. Didn't solve it.
- I have tried with stream flushing. Didn't solve it
- I have tried some fancy libraries and the protobuf-net library. It made things even worse, the header was full of gibberish.

What's interesting is that when I try to serialize these structures to a file using the same methods, that is either the libraries or the write methods of the structures, it works fine, the data stored in the file is the right one, but when I send it through a socket, it fails.

Comment: The error is likely on the reading side, please show the C++ deserialization code.

Comment: reading a checksum and treating that as a length sounds a bit... odd; are you sure you are using that right? I have to say, though: I do a *lot* of `Stream` and `Socket` programming. Number of times I use `BinaryReader` / `BinaryWriter`: zero. It simply isn't useful for most protocols

Comment: Oh, and indeed: protobuf-net won't help unless the actual protocol here is protobuf, which I doubt. Do you have a definition of the actual protocol?

Comment: The error is not on the server deserialization. The buffer received by the server is full of zeros, even before I try to deserialize it.

Concerning the protobuf-net, I assume the reason it doesn't help is because, as I understand, the protobuf adds meta data and the only way to make it work is to use protobufs on both side, which is not the case.

The use of word checksum is maybe not the most appropriate but the idea behind is basically a length.

Since you do a lot of Stream ans socket programming what do you use for binary? (apart from protobufs).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, your "alignment" is writing an int instead of a byte.

In your Header class's Write() method, change...

```
    writer.Write(0); //alignement
```

...to...

```
    writer.Write((byte)0); //alignement
```

Then your Read seems to work fine, and any other issue is with your messaging or server side reading.